# Initiate geocomplete on a dynamicaly generated element

Tags: jquery, geocomplete

i would like to have geocomplete work in my form. The problem is the element that suppose to register with goecomplete is dynamically inserted html:

```
function fetch_company_info (id) {
id = typeof id !== 'undefined' ? id : 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch_company_info.php",
    data: { id : id },
    success: function(msg) {


        $('#company_info_container').html(msg); //html of .geocomplete element is generate here

        $(".geocomplete").geocomplete({ //this does not work
            country: "CA"
        });

    }
})
}
```

Comment: `this does not work` is not a proper problem statement. Approach to initializing the plugin is correct assuming plugin function exists

Comment: i mean it does not load. It works on a regular html element. but when i copy the same element to be returned as a part of ajax and insert it with $('#company_info_container').html(msg); it does not work on that element